# antlr4 rule not ignoring standalone open bracket

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

The situation:

```
rule   : block+ ;
block  : '[' String ']' ;
String : ([a-z] | '[' | '\\]')+ ;
```

Trick is **String** can contain **[** without backslash escape and **]** with backslasash escape, so in this example:

```
[hello\]world][hello[[world]
```

First block can be parsed correctly, but the second one... parser is trying find **]** for every **[**. Is there way to say antlr parser to ignore this standalone **[**? I can't change format, but i need to find some workaround with antlr.

PS: Without antlr there is algorythm to avoid this, something like: collect **[** in queue before we will find first **]** and use only head of queue. But I really need antlr =_=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lexer modes.

> Lexical modes allow us to split a single lexer grammar into multiple
>   sublexers. The lexer can only return tokens matched by rules from the
>   current mode.

You can read more about lexer rules in antlr documentation [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md).

First you will need to divide you grammar into separate `lexer` and `parser`. Than just use another mode after you see open bracket.

Parser grammar:

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

rul   : block+ ;
block  : LBR STRING RBR ;
```

Lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

LBR: '[' -> pushMode(InString);

mode InString;

STRING : ([a-z] | '\\]' | '[')+ ;
RBR: ']' -> popMode;
```

Working example is [here](https://github.com/Fantast/stackoverflow-test4).

You can read the documentation on lexer modes

Comment: Yeah, it really works, thanks! But can you explain how exactly it works, in details? I mean, it seems there is important even order of definition of tokens and mode... so if i gonna extend this grammar i need to understand what i am doing =)

Comment: I've added link to the doc into an answer. And yes, the tokens declared after `mode ModeName` directive are corresponding to that mode.